# Is the memory card still recoverable?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, crashes

I had a memory card that was almost full, and recently when I was working with it, it suddenly crashed. The memory card was completely clean and looked like a new memory card. So the problem is not the connections.

I own a Samsung Galaxy. Normally, When I insert the SD card inside, it says "Preparing SD Card (Checking for errors)" and then a few seconds later it becomes available to use.

But when I insert this memory card into the device, the device does not show any reaction.
Neither message nor anything, the device is completely indifferent to its entry and exit.

I do not know if there was any important data in it or not, but I know it would be better if it could be retrieved.

Is the memory card still recoverable?

Comment: Usually Android is not good in reading sd-cards that are not working 100%. Using the card in an USB-SD-Card reader connected to a PC there is a very small chance that some data may get accessible. But often such sd-cards are not recognized at all or shown with a total size of 0 bytes (e.g. in Windows Disc Management).